# How to trigger focusout on an element other than an input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to trigger a `focusout` event on an `ul` element:

```
// HTML
<nav>
  <ul _v-2e9e2f12="">
    <li _v-2e9e2f12="">
      <a _v-2e9e2f12="">
      </a>
      <ul _v-0078ee36="" _v-2e9e2f12="">
        <li>List element</li>
        <li>List element</li>
        <li>List element</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

// JS
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function(ev) {
    var $icon = $(ev.currentTarget)
    var $menu = $icon.next()
    $menu.focus()
    console.log('Focus triggered!')
  });

  $("ul[_v-0078ee36]").focusout(function() {
    console.log('Focusout triggered!')
  });
})
```

But `.focusout` is never triggered.

What's the correct way of doing it?

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d9jm82cb/10/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elements other than input elements cannot be focused unless you give a tab index to them.

```
<ul tabindex="-1" _v-0078ee36="" _v-2e9e2f12="">
```

So if you want to trigger the focus out for a non input element, you have to set its tab index to `-1`.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/d9jm82cb/12/)

Comment: Worked. Thanks again!

Comment: @alexchenco Glad to help! :)